# Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzopen() in /etc/apache2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/smart_ip/includes/smart_ip.utility.inc on line 454

Tags: php, apache, http, zlib

I'm using `centos 6.7`, `http 2.4.17`, `mysql 5.1`, `php 5.5.30`. web page is working fine but at bottom it is giving below error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzopen() in /etc/apache2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/smart_ip/includes/smart_ip.utility.inc on line 454

I've installed zlib through source code but still its not enabling it after configuring php, restarting apache and system.

```
# php -i|grep -i zlib
gzip compression => disabled (install ext/zlib)
```

How to enable gzip compression ?

Comment: try it `yum install zlib-devel`

Comment: already installed zlib-devel

Answer (score 2):

Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to configure PHP `--with-zlib[=DIR]`
Instead, you can use `gzopen64()`. In theory, it works exactly the same way.

This issue occurs because your PHP server is not compiled with Zlib (this PHP module allows you to read and write .gz compressed files). To enable Zlib support in PHP and how to setup Zlip can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.setup.php

Comment: I have recompiled php with all possible flags including zlib. Issue get resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Then recompiled with all possible flags including previous compiled flags, then it works